# Draw in a SVG that was already drawn

Tags: javascript, css, html, svg

I want to know if it's possible and how to draw in an already drawn SVG. Let's say that I've drawn with SVG something, but I want to add another element, without draw again all the map or modify the original cod.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it can be done. Actually, it is one of the advantages of svg. Here is an example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>HTML5 SVG demo</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>SVG DEMO</h1>
        <svg id="circle" height="200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <circle id="greencircle" cx="30" cy="30" r="30" fill="green" />
        </svg>



        <script type="text/javascript">

            var rect = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'rect');
            rect.setAttributeNS(null,"id", "myrect");
            rect.setAttributeNS(null,"fill", "red");
            rect.setAttributeNS(null,"stroke", "black");
            rect.setAttributeNS(null,"stroke-width", "5");
            rect.setAttributeNS(null,"x", "100");
            rect.setAttributeNS(null,"y", "100");
            rect.setAttributeNS(null,"width", "100");
            rect.setAttributeNS(null,"height", "50");
            var svg = document.getElementById("circle");
            svg.appendChild(rect);


        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```